# Android SMS Sending failed,Unable to find out the error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms

Gives An error :"SMS failed,try again later in exception code".
LOG file contains:"01-02 12:00:32.934: W/System.err(9560):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  "
Can any one tell me why the try statement is not working?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.Toast;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  Button sendBtn;
 EditText txtphoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(msg, "The onCreate() event");
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
          sendSMSMessage();
       }
    });
}
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    Log.i("Send SMS", "");

    String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
    String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

    try {
       SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
       smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "SMS faild, please try again.",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


 }
```

Comment: Please post your complete stack trace.

Comment: Describe your question briefly & with maximum information., it will be useful for programmers can give solutions at here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add this import

```
   import android.telephony.SmsManager;
```

No problem in this.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
```

Add user permission in mainfest , as below :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Try it out and say.
update me with queries if this wat your mistake.
Accept answer if you got wat you need.
Happy coding :)